# random numbers previously established (java)

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, random

The following code shows 4 int variables:

```
  int xy1 = 724329;
  int xy2 = 714385;
  int xy3 = 715440;
  int xy4 = 696492;
```

I'm pretending to code an app that, by opening it, shows one of those numbers (NOT numbers between them) on java console, randomly. I know that `Math.Random` class can be used to solve these kind of issues, but I don't know what is the proper way to do so.

So, thanks.

Comment: Put these values in an array, call nextInt() to a Random object and use the value to access the array. Try to come up with a code that does that; if you run into a problem, ask a question here.

Answer (score 4):

Well it sounds like you just want a collection of possible values, and an index between 0 and 3 inclusive:

```
int[] values = { 724329, 714385, 715440, 696492 };
Random random = new Random(); // Ideally initialize once for the entire app
int index = random.nextInt(4);
int value = values[index];
```

Comment: Why not condense to `int value = values[random.nextInt(4)];`? A little annoying to keep `index` in the scope.

Comment: @Bathsheba: It makes the code clearer, IMO. In my own code I may well do it that way - but I'm trying to explain the code to the OP, and the extra variable helps. Besides, this is likely to be within a pretty small scope, so an extra explanatory variable doesn't hurt. Would you rather I used `int value = new int[] { 724329, 714385, 715440, 696492 }[new Random().nextInt(4)];`?

Comment: The one-liner raises eyebrows due to maintainability and it's also nice to separate program data. I'm also unsure about continuously initialising `Random`. So that would be a step too far.

Comment: @Bathsheba: I wouldn't continuously initialize `Random` either, hence the comment in the answer. But do you agree that for a newcomer, separating the two operations (generating the index and using it) simplifies things? Always bear the audience in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Place them into an array and use Random to select a number between 0-3 and use it as a key to select the value from the array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

This line

```
r.nextInt(nums.length)
```

selects an integer from 0 to nums.length-1.

Then I print out the randomly selected number from the nums array.
I repeat this 20 times just for demonstration purposes.

```
import java.util.Random;


public class Test015 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] nums = {724329, 714385, 715440, 696492};
        Random r = new Random();
        for (int i=0; i<20; i++){
            int index = r.nextInt(nums.length);
            System.out.println("Number randomly chosen: " + nums[index]);
        }
    }

}
```